# Is there a special name for planar graphs, when the outer face has the highest degree?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Is there a special name for planar graphs, when the outer face has the highest degree?

$\hskip1.3in$[image]

Like $a)$, where $f_{\text{outer}}=6$; not like $b)$, where $f_{\text{outer}}=4$...

Comment: Isn't it sometimes possible to draw the graph in a different way so that a different face is the outer one? (I guess if you still need the drawing to be planar then the answer *might* be no, but I'd be a little surprised). In other words I'm concerned that the outer face might not be uniquely determined by the graph, but is a property of the particular drawing.

Comment: @MattPressland: Not just sometimes.  You can "invert" around any face to make it the outer face.  That is, if
$p$ is any point in the interior, map the complex plane by $z \to 1/(z-p)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Now you've confirmed my suspicion I can even see why this must be true; add a point in the outer face so the drawing is on the sphere, and then remove one inside a different face. So my worry was correct - there can't be a name for such graphs, because it's not a property of the graph. It is a property of the picture, but I would be surprised if it has been named.

Comment: @RobertIsrael & Matt but I remember [Whitney saying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Properties): "*However, if the graph is 3-connected, I showed that the embedding [, and thus the dual graph,] is unique.*" And even if not, then there is one where the highest degree is at the outer face. I just want to nail this representation down with descirbing word...

Comment: The embedding is unique (up to isotopy, of course) *in the sphere*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez great, thanks. Someone should update the wiki page...